# I am trying to complete an else if statment in Java but it doesnt work

Tags: java, if-statement

I want it to print "C" if 'salary' is equal to or greater than 50 but I want it to print "E" if 'salary' is greater than 70.
How should I go about doing this?
*(P.S I am using programiz online java complier)*
Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; 

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your Name, Student ID and Salary: \n");

    // String input
    String name = myObj.nextLine();

    // Numerical input
    int id = myObj.nextInt();
    int salary = myObj.nextInt();

    // Output input by user
    System.out.println("\nStudent Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("\nStudent ID: " + "IIBT" + id);
    System.out.println("\nDate of Issue: " + java.time.LocalDate.now());
    System.out.println("\nDocument ID: " + salary);

    if(salary>=50) {    
        if(salary>=70) {
             System.out.printIn("E");
             }
        else {
             System.out.println("C");
             }
        
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Your `else` needs to be _after_ the if-statement, not inside it.

Comment: Something like this? yet it still doesnt work

Comment: Now you have a logical problem. Your `else if` block can only be executed if salary is less than 50, but not less than 70, which is impossible. I suggest you switch the order of your conditions.

Comment: I'd also suggest writing the conditions as `salary >= 50` and `salary >= 70`... most people find "variable part first" a much simpler way to read conditions. (It's a more direct way of representing the requirement as you've written it, too: "if 'salary' is equal to or greater than 50".)

Answer (score 1):

You can of course rank in descending order:

```
    if (salary >= 70) {
        System.out.println("E");
    } else if (salary >= 50) {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
```

Comment: i keep getting the error:

 System.out.printIn("E");
                  ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error

Comment: See typo correction

Answer (score 0):

You could put the second if inside the first.
You could also use a switch.
Personally I find it clearer to write `if(salary>=70)` but there is no functional difference.

```
if(50<=salary) {    
    if(70<=salary) {
         System.out.println("E");
         }
    else {
         System.out.println("C");
         }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting the error:

System.out.printIn("E");
                  ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error

Comment: I copied your code, not noticing that it was printIn with a capital i and not a l ( lower case L) - corrected

Comment: Thanks alot it works now, im suprised i missed something that simple

Comment: Typos happen to me as well :-) please upvote if it helped